# Splitting an eCommerce store from the WordPress Theme

Tags: theme-options

Company I work for has purchased an eCommerce solution for WordPress. The solution works as a complete WordPress Theme. My assignment is to split the store view from the original website design.

To be more precise, website we are working on has a unique design, but when we install the store theme, the whole website theme changes to that of a store.

Are there ways I can complete this assignment? I thought about it for a while but the solution I found is terrible. I wanted to allow access to a store only on one particular page, by checking

```
<?php if is_page('shop') { 
include TEMPLATEPATH.'storeurl/header.php'; 
} else { 
get_header(); 
} ?>
```

and so on, but it gets me nowhere because I need to have certain fields in admin panel for adding products.

Any other ideas, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core site functionality really shouldn't be so tightly coupled to the theme. This is why the plugin system exists. If it's not too late I would recommend exploring alternatives.

That said, anything happening on the admin side is in the theme's `functions.php` file, or is included via that file. As long as that file and anything it loads is in the proper place it's likely the admin side will work. Then it's a matter of merging or including the other templates into your own theme to get the presentation you want on the front end.